# How to use tf dataset sharding AFTER a shuffle operation, but not repeat entries

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to solve the following problem:
I have 128 files that I want to break into 4 subsets. Each time around, I want the division to be different.

If I do `tf.data.Dataset.list_files('glob_pattern', shuffle=False)`, the dataset has the right number of files. Sharding this works as expected, but each shard only ever has the same files.

I want to shard and end up with a different division of the files each go-through the data. However, if I turn `shuffle=True`, then each shard seems to have its own copy of the original dataset, meaning that I can see the same file multiple times before seeing all the files once.

Is there an idiomatic way of splitting these files?

Basically, I'm wondering why the original `list_files` dataset is able to have some files show up multiple times before all the files have been seen.

Here is some TF2.0 code to see the problem:

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([f'train_{str(i).zfill(5)}' for i in range(128)])
ds = ds.shuffle(128)

n_splits = 4
sub_datasets = [ds.shard(n_splits, i) for i in range(n_splits)]

output = [] 

# go through each of the subsets 
for i in range(n_splits): 
    results = [x.numpy().decode() for x in sub_datasets[i]]
    output.extend(results)

print(len(set(output)), 'is the number of unique files seen (128 desired)')
```

Comment: Hi mrngbaeb. Do you want to end up with 4 individual datasets at the end? Or one dataset with the 4 batches/splits?

Comment: The ultimate goal is to get 4 datasets that I will then interleave later. So for this part of the question, I want four datasets, each of which has a random subset of the original files. And I want those partitions to change each go-around.

Comment: Ok. My answer below should answer this for you. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer from what I can understand of your question. To generate a new subset of 4 datasets (shared) each time randomly shuffled, you can use the following code.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# ####################
# I used numbers for visualization ... feel free to replace with your demo code
# ####################
#   ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([f'train_{str(i).zfill(5)}' for i in range(128)])
# ####################
arr = np.arange(128)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(arr)

def get_four_datasets(original_ds, window_size=32, shuffle_size=128):
    """ Every time you call this function you will get a new four datasets """
    return original_ds.shuffle(shuffle_size).window(window_size)

remake_ds_1 = list()
remake_ds_2 = list()
for i, (dataset_1, dataset_2) in enumerate(zip(get_four_datasets(ds), get_four_datasets(ds))):
    print(f"\n\nDATASET #1-{i+1}")
    ds_subset = [value for value in dataset_1.as_numpy_iterator()]
    print("\t", ds_subset)
    remake_ds_1.extend(ds_subset)

    print(f"\nDATASET #2-{i+1}")
    ds_subset_2 = [value for value in dataset_2.as_numpy_iterator()]
    print("\t", ds_subset_2)
    remake_ds_2.extend(ds_subset_2)

print("\n\nCounts\n")
print("DS 1 ALL: ", len(remake_ds_1))
print("DS 1 UNIQUE: ", len(set(remake_ds_1)))
print("DS 2 ALL: ", len(remake_ds_2))
print("DS 2 UNIQUE: ", len(set(remake_ds_2)))
```

**OUTPUT**

```sh
DATASET #1-1
     [96, 4, 66, 120, 42, 54, 110, 57, 67, 7, 13, 9, 69, 86, 122, 88, 10, 55, 27, 106, 77, 107, 114, 87, 59, 81, 1, 49, 118, 17, 36, 11]

DATASET #2-1
     [47, 26, 122, 10, 110, 31, 86, 34, 52, 121, 36, 112, 55, 48, 50, 108, 100, 103, 113, 68, 58, 29, 32, 84, 124, 15, 38, 51, 6, 66, 24, 41]


DATASET #1-2
     [56, 80, 94, 124, 52, 109, 83, 90, 112, 35, 6, 101, 20, 84, 73, 74, 100, 99, 108, 15, 14, 12, 89, 24, 8, 29, 68, 85, 125, 3, 33, 58]

DATASET #2-2
     [125, 127, 74, 97, 12, 39, 109, 126, 98, 40, 99, 93, 35, 107, 91, 88, 45, 13, 106, 120, 19, 73, 83, 11, 105, 61, 16, 114, 79, 95, 94, 44]


DATASET #1-3
     [105, 38, 43, 60, 0, 26, 127, 65, 22, 18, 123, 82, 121, 71, 51, 23, 113, 30, 63, 40, 2, 61, 16, 98, 64, 25, 41, 28, 45, 19, 117, 39]

DATASET #2-3
     [75, 64, 1, 17, 7, 42, 80, 92, 3, 9, 54, 33, 82, 56, 118, 102, 115, 43, 28, 90, 60, 119, 0, 57, 123, 62, 22, 72, 65, 23, 30, 87]


DATASET #1-4
     [48, 62, 31, 102, 111, 46, 103, 44, 116, 79, 21, 50, 53, 78, 93, 32, 95, 34, 92, 126, 104, 47, 119, 37, 5, 70, 97, 91, 76, 75, 72, 115]

DATASET #2-4
     [4, 85, 21, 116, 78, 27, 117, 2, 59, 111, 69, 46, 63, 20, 49, 5, 81, 53, 18, 37, 8, 76, 71, 89, 14, 104, 25, 96, 67, 101, 77, 70]


Counts

DS 1 ALL: 128
DS 1 UNIQUE: 128
DS 2 ALL: 128
DS 2 UNIQUE: 128
```

---

If you just want to generate a dataset where every 32 examples pulled from the dataset is shuffled and you want to iterate over the dataset multiple times getting new 32-set samples every time, you can do the following.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

arr = np.arange(128)
N_REPEATS = 10


ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(arr)
ds = ds.shuffle(128).batch(32).repeat(N_REPEATS)
```

**OUTPUT**

```sh
BATCH 1: [92, 94, 76, 38, 58, 9, 44, 16, 86, 28, 64, 7, 60, 42, 31, 0, 46, 1, 83, 57, 18, 102, 67, 110, 113, 101, 93, 61, 96, 17, 105, 6]
BATCH 2: [59, 15, 121, 3, 72, 100, 50, 52, 45, 23, 87, 43, 33, 29, 62, 25, 74, 65, 75, 68, 4, 56, 117, 47, 73, 109, 106, 35, 88, 91, 119, 66]
BATCH 3: [98, 78, 125, 24, 99, 51, 14, 114, 26, 22, 54, 89, 79, 63, 30, 124, 20, 13, 2, 34, 95, 41, 85, 39, 37, 77, 90, 107, 104, 118, 27, 97]
BATCH 4: [49, 5, 53, 115, 126, 40, 108, 48, 8, 84, 120, 32, 82, 11, 112, 55, 80, 69, 12, 70, 111, 123, 81, 116, 71, 122, 36, 21, 103, 19, 127, 10]
BATCH 5: [74, 61, 97, 6, 127, 119, 65, 15, 78, 72, 99, 18, 41, 76, 79, 33, 0, 105, 103, 46, 14, 50, 113, 26, 43, 45, 100, 90, 28, 48, 19, 9]
BATCH 6: [35, 20, 3, 64, 5, 96, 114, 34, 126, 85, 124, 69, 110, 54, 109, 24, 104, 32, 73, 92, 11, 13, 58, 107, 84, 88, 59, 75, 95, 40, 16, 101]
BATCH 7: [93, 66, 106, 44, 102, 125, 7, 30, 12, 116, 87, 111, 81, 56, 83, 37, 31, 77, 67, 21, 118, 1, 120, 36, 86, 62, 71, 98, 82, 52, 25, 27]
BATCH 8: [112, 68, 60, 70, 115, 117, 29, 91, 57, 10, 121, 89, 4, 2, 122, 39, 51, 22, 53, 63, 108, 94, 42, 17, 8, 23, 80, 38, 55, 49, 47, 123]
BATCH 9: [67, 20, 101, 123, 109, 4, 39, 65, 34, 71, 22, 62, 73, 81, 114, 112, 66, 35, 43, 49, 92, 68, 1, 54, 27, 103, 46, 12, 82, 6, 119, 99]
BATCH 10: [86, 69, 13, 44, 16, 50, 75, 61, 58, 104, 64, 47, 95, 10, 79, 70, 97, 63, 45, 17, 56, 74, 87, 53, 91, 21, 48, 76, 9, 51, 28, 126]
...
...
...
BATCH 40: [10, 41, 29, 39, 57, 127, 101, 106, 55, 62, 72, 76, 124, 81, 66, 126, 53, 24, 33, 49, 102, 75, 34, 61, 47, 15, 21, 121, 8, 94, 52, 13]
```

Please let me know if I misunderstood and I can update accordingly.

Comment: this is getting closer -- but what if I want to use 'Dataset 1' in the above example many times? If I look at the first few elements of `ds` several times, they are random, as I would expect. But if I look at the first few elements of `dataset 1` after defining it, they are always the same. This means I have to call `get_four_datasets` each time that I go around the epoch, which I would rather not do... Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want to shuffle within the dataset you simply need to add .shuffle(32).repeat(N_REPEATS) to each individual dataset. This guarantees that every time you iterate over a shard it will yield the same 32 samples in a different order. And if you want every epoch to have a random shared 32 sample subset, you won't be able to and also separate the datasets. You'll be forced to operate on a single dataset. i.e. ds = orig_ds.shuffle(128).batch(32).repeat(N_REPEATS)

Comment: ah, ok. thanks for your help! I think what you're saying is correct, and I won't be able to have 4 sub-datasets that each epoch, get a different random subset (at least not without major engineering work).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `reshuffle_each_iteration=False`:

```
ds = ds.shuffle(128, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)
```

Full code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([f'train_{str(i).zfill(5)}' for i in range(128)])
ds = ds.shuffle(128, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)

n_splits = 4
sub_datasets = [ds.shard(n_splits, i) for i in range(n_splits)]

output = []

# go through each of the subsets
for i in range(n_splits):
    results = [x.numpy().decode() for x in sub_datasets[i]]
    output.extend(results)

print(len(set(output)), 'is the number of unique files seen (128 desired)')
```

```
128 is the number of unique files seen (128 desired)
```

Comment: This is not what I want!
I want to have it go through each file in a different order every time -- but not do any repeats.

Comment: This is exactly what it does

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this code shuffles the input files ONCE and then splits it up. If you repeat this dataset, each subset will have the same files each time. 
I want the subsets to change their contents after each go-through.